# Are two latitudes parallel each other?

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I have read that there are no parallel lines on the surface of a sphere. Are two latitudes on a sphere parallel? Anyone, please elaborate.

Comment: Is a line "the shortest distance between two points" to you?

Comment: As @LordSharktheUnknown suggests, for discussions like this, it's important that we agree on how terms are defined. In spherical geometry, a "line" is specifically a *great circle*. (A great circle gives the shortest distance between two points. A great circle has zero "geodesic curvature". A great circle is uniquely determined by two (non-antipodal) points.) In that regard, the answer you seek is in the question: two distinct latitudes can't be parallel lines, because there's only one latitude that is a line; namely, the Equator. For more insights, search the site for, say, "line on sphere".

Comment: Thank you @Blue